# How do I display multiple charts automatically with PHP and MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql, highcharts

I have the following problem. I want to make multiple Highcharts webcharts appear automatically based on the data from the database. Let's say we have the following database:

```
___________________________________________________________________
|       |           |      |               |            |          |
| Year  |   Month   |  ID  |  Name User    |   Wins     |  Losses  |
|_______|___________|______|_______________|____________|__________|
| 2013       1         21     Tony Stark        3            12    |    
| 2013       1         52    Bruce Wayne        5            4     |
| 2013       1         76     Clark Kent        9            5     |
|__________________________________________________________________|
```

(This database is an example, there are a lot more rows in the real database.)

And I have the following query:

```
SELECT
            a.year AS year1,
            a.month AS month1,
            a.id AS id,
            a.name AS nameuser,
            a.wins AS wins,
            a.losses AS losses
            FROM Sales a
        WHERE
        a.month = 1 AND
        a.year = YEAR(NOW())
```

With this, it is very easy to hardcode a chart with Highcharts. But what I want is that there has to be a webchart per user. So instead of a single webchart with all the users in it, I want multiple charts next to each other based on the data from the database.

So instead of this:

http://jsfiddle.net/CWSb6/

[image: Single chart with all users]

I want this (But then next to each other):

http://jsfiddle.net/DReMD/

[image: Multiple charts, one per user]

It has to be generated automatically with php and mysql. So if there is a new user starting this month, and the new user is saved in the database, the page automatically displays the new user with the related web chart.

I find this very hard to accomplish and I need some help to get to the right direction for the solution.

EDIT:

This is what I currently have:

```
<?php
$sql    = "SELECT
            a.year AS year1,
            a.month AS month1,
            a.id AS id,
            a.name AS nameuser,
            a.wins AS wins,
            a.losses AS losses
            FROM Sales a
        WHERE
        a.month = 1 AND
        a.year = YEAR(NOW())"; 
        $result = $adb->pquery($sql, array());
         while ($row = $adb->fetch_array($result)) {


             ?>                 
<script> 
$(function () {

$("#webchart<? echo $row["id"] ?>").highcharts({

    chart: {
        polar: true,
        type: "line"
    },

    title: {
        text: "",
        x: -80
    },
     legend: {
        enabled: false

        },
        exporting: {
        enabled: false
        },
        credits: {
        enabled: false
        },
    pane: {
        size: "80%"
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: ["wins", "losses", "etc", "test", 
                "junk"],
        tickmarkPlacement: "on",
        lineWidth: 0
    },

    yAxis: {
        gridLineInterpolation: "polygon",
        lineWidth: 0,
        min: 0
    },

    legend: {
        verticalAlign: "bottom",
        y: 100,
        layout: "vertical"
    },

    series: [{
        name: "test",
        data: [ <? echo $row["wins"] . ", " . $row["losses"] . ", " . $row["etc"] . ", " . $row["test"] . ", " .$row["junk"] ?>],
        pointPlacement: "on"
    }]
});
});
</script> 
<div id="webchart<? echo $row["id"] ?>" style="min-width: 300px; height: 300px; margin:0 auto;"></div>
<?} ?>
```

The problem is that this loop returns nothing. (And yes I have placed the div with the correct id).

Comment: `... WHERE \`username\` = 'Clark Kent' AND ...` ?

Comment: That is not what i want. The reason that I don't use that is that every user must have a personal webchart. So the charts must display automatically per user generated from the database. I will edit the question a bit.

Comment: Each chart can get data via i.e ajax or use php printed variables. Examples of common PHP / databaes and highcharts http://docs.highcharts.com/#preprocessing.

Comment: $("#webchart<? echo $row["id"] ?>") this line is incorrect, try to use $('#webchart'+<? echo $row["id"] ?>+')... Because in your code it is not parsed to PHP.

Comment: you are missing semi-colons at the end of several lines: <? echo $row["id"] ?> should be <? echo $row["id"]; ?>. This could be causing the script not to run. Are you getting any output at all or any errors, or just a blank page?

Answer (score 0):

Mmmm,  i think you code is almost correct, but,  from where you get the fields
etc, test and junk?  i try your code, using mysqli, i guess is the same you are using, but your query never returns this data. if  you changue

```
data: [ <?php echo $row["wins"] . ", " . $row["losses"] . ", " . $row["etc"] . ", " .     $row["test"] . ", " .$row["junk"] ?>],
```

for:

```
data: [ <?php echo $row["wins"] . ", " . $row["losses"] . ", " . $row["losses"] . ", " . $row["losses"] . ", " .$row["losses"] ?>],
```

this work for me.

i hope this helps you.

Good Luck.